# Observer Pattern and SpringBoot @Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Could anyone help me how to handle ***observer pattern*** and SpringBoot @Service?

Let's imagine I have class:

```
WeatherStation[temperature, humidity, windSpeed ...] - subject (observable)
```

I can have a lot of these classes and I need to update the data in database, so when temperature changes I need to log it to database under correct WeatherStation.

I came with three solutions, first is:

> Create class WeatherStationObserver which would have reference to WeatherStationRepository and  I would register one WeatherStationObserver for one WeatherStation and the WeatherStationObserver would save the data to database (this is similar how I have it implemented right now) but there are some caviats. For example I can not @Autowire to WeatherStationObserver and I can not make the methods @Transactional ...

Second idea is:

> Create WeatherStationUpdateService which would be called from WeatherStationObserver. I don't like this because the WeatherStationObserver serves here only to call the WeatherStationUpdateService.

Third idea:

> Make the service an observer and register it for each WeatherStation  but I am not sure if the service should not be called only from outside and if it is good practise service to behave as observer.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: Why do you have "a lot of these classes"? 

How does the data from these weather stations get to your server?

Are you getting data sent from one station at a time...or is there some kinda gateway that means you are getting say 300 weather station values in one HTTP request to process?

Comment: Hi, thanks for question, I am communicating with WeatherStations independently over OPC UA. So one WeatherStation class represent one physical weather station and so the data are updated independently on others.

Comment: I may have an idea. I am guessing each has an ID you reference?

Comment: Yes and no, the WeatherStation class doesn't have ID reference but it has IP address which has to be unique so it can serve as ID for searching in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the weather stations in database with their corresponding IDs.

Along side each have a "last polled at" time.

Have an `@Scheduled and @Transactional` task that pulls a page of say 20 stations that have not been polled recently (within x seconds) and queries them for their data, handle it and persist it updating the "last polled at" for each.

If you MUST have them all as close together, then do your OPC UA data fetching and as each comes back, just put the data on a queue (ActiveMQ for example) and then have an `@JmsListener` that will handle that queue, pulling on at a time doing the persisting (to not hit the database hard).

Comment: I am not sure I understand this solution. My question was pretty much if service can be an OBSERVER of WeatherStation class. You can check the PlcAutomaticUpdateServiceImpl class [here](https://github.com/bzumik1/metalForming/tree/ConnectionRefactoring). The weather station was just simplified example.

Comment: Ah sorry, you mean say if a field in one of "WeatherStation" is changed, then certain `@services` are invoked?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :)

Comment: Maybe this is something that you may use?
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Comment: I have a working solution I am just not sure if it is the best way (correct) how to do it. On the WeatherStation example it would look like that i need to do weatherStation.register(weateherStationService). Then WeatherStationService includes method onChange(WeatherStation weatherStation) and in this method I am updating the repository.